# What vimrc setting controls number of scroll lines

Tags: vim

When using `Ctrl-E` and `Ctrl-Y` in vim, I would like it to scroll multiple lines instead of one at a time.  How would I set up my vimrc to specify the number of lines for just these 2 commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override the default bindings with counted versions.

```
noremap <C-e> 2<C-e>
noremap <C-y> 2<C-y>
```

Use `noremap` to avoid recursion.

Comment: This is it!  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is not *exactly* what you want, but I hope it helps.

Regarding `Ctrl+E` and `Ctrl+Y`, I'm afraid that the only way may be to precede the command with a line count. So, if you want to scroll down five lines, you press `5`, then `Ctrl+E`.

But you can, by default, use `Ctrl+D` to scroll half a page downwards, and `Ctrl+U` to scroll half a page upwards, and you can also `set` how many lines you want to go up or down with the `scroll` variable.

So, in your `.vimrc`, add the line `set scroll=N`, where `N` is the number of lines you want to scroll with the `Ctrl+D` and `Ctrl+U` commands.

Comment: Thanks.  @chepner has the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do any particular setup. Instead, you can just scroll one page at a time using `CTRL+F` (forward) or `CTRL+B` (backwards) as an alternative solution.

Comment: I'm aware of that option but it also moves the cursor.  Sometimes I need to move the window and leave the cursor on the same line.